# how to send a table for odbc in vb

Tags: vb.net, odbc

I'm trying to send a table for odbc in vb. the datatable parameter is P_DETALLE, but I get an error like this:

> There is no assignment of object type System.Data.DataTable to a native type of a known managed provider

the code is something like this:

```
Sub ADMINISTRAR_ARTEFACTO(ByVal P As E_ARTEFACTO)
    Dim CONECTION As New OdbcConnection
    Try
        CONECTION.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ALURHE_DBConnectionString_64").ConnectionString + ";pwd=123"
        Dim COMMAND As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("{call SP_ADM_ARTEFACTO (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", CONECTION)

        With COMMAND

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_SERIE", P.P_SERIE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_ARTEFACTO", P.P_TIPO_ARTEFACTO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MODELO", P.P_MODELO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_MARCA", P.P_MARCA)

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_DETALLE", P.P_DETALLE)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_USUARIO", P.P_USUARIO)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_ID_ARTEFACTO", If(P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M", P.P_ID_ARTEFACTO, DBNull.Value))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("V_TIPO_OPERACION", P.P_TIPO_OPERACION)


        End With


        'If P.P_TIPO_OPERACION = "M" Then
        '    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_PRODUCTO", P.P_ID_PRODUCTO)
        'End If

        CONECTION.Open()
        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CONECTION.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        If (CONECTION.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            CONECTION.Close()
        End If

        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DataTable` cannot be the value of a command parameter with the ODBC provider, [it is not supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctype(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

You could do it with the MSSQL provider if you specified `SqlDbType.Structured`.

One thing you could do is insert the data in from your `DataTable` into a temp table and then do a join on that table in your query/procedure.

Comment: If your data table isn't too large just loop over the rows and insert each one into a temp or stage table. I don't know your data so I can't write the query with the JOIN but it would be very similar to what your procedure already has.

Comment: You can give me a simple example please

Comment: or can you tell me that other method than ODBC ?, I'm using postgresql with vb

Comment: [Maybe this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320418/insert-the-whole-value-of-datatable-bulk-into-postgresql-table), it is difficult to get specific because I have no idea what the structure of your DataTable is or what is in your procedure.

Comment: Npgsql supports datatable?

Comment: I don't think it supports it as a parameter, the example is using `NpgsqlDataAdapter` to perform updates based on the state of the DataRows if you are familiar with using adapters.

Comment: Is there a way to send a datatable parameter?

Comment: Not that I am aware of but I don't use postgres

Comment: but I mean in vb

Comment: The .Net provider must support it as the MSSQL provider supports SqlDbType.Structured. I don't think the postgress provider for .Net supports it. You will need to find another way, it seems to me you could accomplish the same thing in your stored procedure by accessing a table that has the data from your DataTable.